# How to select a small part of very large vector in time?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, vector

I have a vector with a name `stim`. The length of the vector is
 `len(stim)=600000`. The vector stim has `600000` indices over time. The vector is given below.

```
In [168]:stim

Out[168]:
array([-111.94824219,  -81.80664062,   10.21972656, ...,    9.78515625,
     24.11132812,   50.25390625])
```

Now I want to select a small part of this vector , say from `stim[60]` to `stim[50]`
and then create a new vector and assign this small  sliced part of vector `stim` to a new one, say `stim_sliced`.

I would appreciate the help. I am using python 3.

Comment: What's wrong with `stim_sliced = stim[50:60]`?  That's standard Python slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to Paul Cornelius' answer:
Python3 `slice` is the way to go, as its efficiency is the same as `for x in range` and `getitem` - they both are O(k) where k is the number of items, while `slice` is shorter.
You can't get any better with long vectors than this.